# How do you traverse to the end of a linked list?

Tags: java

Can someone explain me what does

```
current = current.getnext();
```

really mean from the following code ?

```
public void add(Object data)
// post: appends the specified element to the end of this list.
{
    Node temp = new Node(data);
    Node current = head;
    // starting at the head node, crawl to the end of the list
    while(current.getNext() != null)
    {
        current = current.getNext();
    }
    // the last node's "next" reference set to our new node
    current.setNext(temp);
    listCount++;// increment the number of elements variable
}
```

Comment: it means that you want to move from the current element to the next (linked) one. The check in while makes sure such element exists before you move towards it. When you get to the end, you are adding a new element to your linked list.

Comment: Maybe change while loop to `while(current.hasNext()) { ... }` otherwise body of the loop unnecessary. Leave just `while((current = current.getNext()) != null) ;` and it will get you to the end of the list